# Automatic changes to $PATH in Bash

Tags: bash, path

The project I work on has some executable scripts in the repository. These scripts are actually tools that automate some development tasks and I invoke them only when I'm inside the repo and they work only on files in the repo. My typical working session looks like this:

```
$ cd $REPO
$ ./tools/start-session
$ some-script some arguments
$ other-script other arguments
```

In other words, the `start-session` script just adds an appropriate entry to the `$PATH` variable.

I'd like to automate it further so that I don't have to call the `$REPO/tools/start-session` script. What I'd like to achieve is to make bash automatically detect that I'm in my repo dir and append proper entry to `$PATH`. The point is that I have many working copies of my repo and the tools differ a bit in each branch, I move between working copies frequently and I'd like my shell to kind of guess which script I want to invoke.

How do I do that?

The only thing I can think of is that the `$PS1` variable gets executed each time a command is completed, so I could somehow hook some `$PATH`-changing script in there using backticks, i.e. do some thing like

```
PS1=`update-path`$PS1
```

But this seems not the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the right track, but don't use `PS1` - you want `PROMPT_COMMAND`. For example:

```
 PROMPT_COMMAND='ls'
```

will execute `ls` every time a new prompt appears. Whether this will solve you root problem I couldn't say, as I'm not sure I understand it properly.

Comment: That's it! I suppose then, that PS1 should be lightweight and take care of only displaying the prompt, whereas the PROMPT_COMMAND can do any heavyweight stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a simple bash script - let's call it cs (change session) - which changes directory and updates path, so instead of

```
$ cd $REPO
$ ./tools/start-session
$ some-script some arguments
$ other-script other arguments
```

you will do

```
$ cs $REPO
$ some-script some arguments
$ other-script other arguments
```

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
./tools/start-session
```